# different app name for different country

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, ios9

I have released a German app for iPhone (swift 2 ios 9).
Now I would like to add the English language.
The problem is, that my app name will not be understood in countries with English language. It should still be the same app, but use another name for the app in English speaking countries. In Germany the app is called "iPhone App German", and in English speaking countries "App English".

Is this possible? Or do I need to publish 2 separate apps to solve this?

Comment: its not possible that you can use same ios App in different country with different name.

you can use localization in your info.plist for changing your app name but on app store apple doesn't allows you to put same name app in different country with diff name.

Comment: You can add localization in-app and on app-store. I am not sure about the app name in menu of iOS devices because that name is generated from the info.plist file and you can't save your edits to a plist file in mainbundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible.
Just add localizations and change name for each.
May look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html).

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much - you save my day :D 
is this all i have to do ? or i have to change the app name in xcode, too?

Comment: For displaying in stores - only in itunesconnect

Comment: Okay, but i see a problem. i have to change also the app icon for english speaking countries? is this possible, too ?

Comment: I'd like to add that this link will also be very helpful for people in a similar dilemma. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

Comment: thanks for this link, but any idea if i can set an app icon for each country?

Comment: I dont think its possible to have different icons for the application based on the Locale